# Force iframe load

Tags: javascript, html

Normally I open a window with javascript to show information about a upload progress,
but it doesn't look good and many users uses popup blockers.

So I thought I could show these information in an iframe,
but the iframe doesn't load during the upload.

But if I open the iframe during the upload in a new window/tab if loads.

How could I force that the iframe should be loaded?

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
    document.getElementById('iframe').innerHTML = '<iframe src="./stats.php?id=123456"></iframe>';
}
</script>

<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input id="upload" name="upload" size="30" type="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" onclick="test();">
</form>

<div id="iframe"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give the iFrame an id, say iframe1, then run:

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

which is technically incorrect but widely supported, or:

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentDocument.defaultView.location.reload();
```

which is correct but not supported by IE.

Comment: Okay, I get this error: FIREBUG WARNING: ReferenceError: Window is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess it's because once the form is being posted, the current page won't load anything else since it's already sending data and loading the new page, `upload.php`.

Perhaps using an AJAX file uploader would be a better idea? [Here's one](http://seemysites.net/projFolder/uploader/) I found via Google that looks good.

Comment: You might be right, but I already used a Ajax-Uploader and it's similar:
Every Ajax-Request takes more than 10 seconds, so it's useless and I drive better with the iframe.